# A scope below the global scope in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, scoping

I'm new to JS, node, and scoping as a result. I've seen many people say to never use globals and others say to use them extremely sparingly. Basically, I have a function that declares/resets variables.

```
function resetStuff(){
    var foo = '';
    var bar = false;
    ...
}
```

and a socket.io handler.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('event1', function (data){
        if (foo == 'bar') {
            doStuff()
        }
    });
});
```

To me it seems like I would have to move `foo` and `bar` to the global scope, but is there any way to give the socket.io events access to them without doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, node.js has a module scope. so, every variable outside the function just module scope, not Global. ( not like js in client browser, where every variable not in a function will be in Global scope)

so, you could:

```
var foo,bar;

io.on ....
```

and also, you could define a unamed scope by using unnamed function:

```
(function(){
    var foo,bar;

    io.on ....
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could I declare variables in the module scope and then access them from the reset function and the io events? I think that would solve my problem.

Comment: @Radon348 yes. but as your module became large, those variable may become unmanaged, may cause errors,  I suggest you put those code in a unnamed scope.